# Botão em CSS Desalinhado no input de formulário, mas correto em outros tipos de chamada CSS

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4

Tenho um formulário com o código a seguir:

```
div class="container">
<!-- Formulário de Login -->
<form action="validacao.php" target="_blank" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Dados de Login</legend>
        <label for="txUsuario">E-Mail</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" name="usuario" id="txUsuario" required autocomplete="off" />
        <label for="txSenha">Senha</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" required="required" name="senha" id="txSenha" required autocomplete="off" />

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Entrar na Área Administrativa" />
    </fieldset>
</form>


<br>
<br>
<p><b><a class="btn" href="../cadastros/cadastro_candidato.html">Criar uma Conta</a></b></p>
<br>
<br>
```

Mas o primeiro botão, o texto fica desalinhado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu CSS da classe btn é:

```
.btn {
    padding: 0 30px;
    height: 33px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: steelblue;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn.verde {
    background-color: #07b690;
}

.btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #ccc;
}
```

Como posso fazer o primeiro botão ficar com o texto alinhado corretamente?

Comment: Deu certo @dvd muito obrigado! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retire o `height` do `.btn` e ajuste a altura com `padding`, tipo:

```
       top/bottom
          ↓
padding: 10px 30px;
               ↑
          right/left
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
.btn {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: steelblue;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn.verde {
    background-color: #07b690;
}

.btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
<!-- Formulário de Login -->
<form action="validacao.php" target="_blank" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Dados de Login</legend>
        <label for="txUsuario">E-Mail</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" name="usuario" id="txUsuario" required autocomplete="off" />
        <label for="txSenha">Senha</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" required="required" name="senha" id="txSenha" required autocomplete="off" />

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Entrar na Área Administrativa" />
    </fieldset>
</form>


<br>
<br>
<p><b><a class="btn" href="../cadastros/cadastro_candidato.html">Criar uma Conta</a></b></p>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Excelente @dvd!